# unusual output of the hexadecimal number

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main()                              
{                        
    int a = 0xabcdef;

    char *b = &a;
    printf("%x",*b);

    return 0;
}
```

above code gives output as `ffffffef`. What is the reason of this output?

Comment: This is Undefined Behaviour, but you're just taking the LS byte (0xef) -- because apparently your system is little endian -- and then treating it as an int and sign-extending it.

Comment: @user3411451: Why are you ignoring diagnostic messages from your compiler? The initialization of `b` with `&a` is illegal. If you really want to do this, you must use an explicit cast.

Comment: Always run your compiler in the strictest error-checking mode available. *At the very least* this should include `-Wall -Werror` (if using GCC), and there are *lots* of additional warning options available.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `*b` is a `char` type pointer and it's pointing to a `int` type variable. That's the reason of wrong output. Declare the pointer variable `*b` as `int` type.

```
int a = 0xabcdef;    

int *b = &a;
printf("%x",*b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, variable `b` is declared with type `char *`. You are trying to initialize it with value `&a` of type `int *`. This is illegal. The code is not valid C. The behavior is undefined.

Secondly, if your compiler managed to let this initialization slip through, then it probably performed an implicit conversion of the `int *` value to `char *` type. This makes pointer `b` to point to just one byte of variable `a`. The value of that single byte is what you see through `*b`. Which byte that is (in terms of the original value of `a`) is implementation-defined. E.g. you will typically you get a lower-order byte (`0xEF`) or a higher-order byte (`0xAB`).

Thirdly, it is implementation-defined whether type `char` is signed or unsigned. That means that the value of `*b` might be signed or unsigned, depending on your implementation. When you pass a `char` value `*b` to a variadic function `printf`, that `char` value is automatically converted to `int` type.  The result of that conversion will generally depend on the signedness of type `char`. If your `b` points to the `0xEF` byte, `char` is signed and `int` is 32-bit wide and uses 2's-complement, then the result, in hex terms, will look as `0xFFFFFFEF` (which is a negative value).

Fourthly, `%x` format specifier requires an `unsigned int` argument, but instead you are passing an `int` argument with potentially negative value. The behavior is undefined.

In other words, your program is just a big pile of undefined and implementation-defined behavior. There's not much point in trying to explain why you got that specific output.